# Get value from input-tag that is conditionally visible with *ngIf

Tags: html, angular

I've got a simple form in HTML. Depending on the option chosen with the radio button, there are different input fields visible, using *ngIf.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><label>name</label></td>
        <td><input #name /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="contact" value="phone" (click)="usePhone(true)" #p>
            <label for"p">phone</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="contact" value="email" (click)="usePhone(false)" #m>
            <label for"m">email</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngIf="phone">
        <td><label>phone</label></td>
        <td><input #phone /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngIf="!phone">
        <td><label>email</label></td>
        <td><input #email /></td>
    </tr>
 <table>
```

In the TypeScript file, I declare a varibale "phone" of the type boolean and a method:

```
usePhone(phone: boolean): void {
    this.phone = phone
}
```

Now, I want to get the values when clicking on a button:

```
<button (click)="add(name.value, phone.value, email.value);">
    OK
</button>
```

**But when I try it, the browser console says that phone is undefined, even when it is chosen and visible. When I delete the *ngIf statements, so that everything is visible, it works properly. What can I do?**

Comment: Remember that the `ngIf`directive is not hidding/showing elements, is actually removing them from the dom. Also, if you have the value in your component (`this.phone`)  you don't need to send that value from template, you can access directly from your component class.

Comment: I know that, bu I also tried using "add(name.value, phone.value)" to test whether the problem is, that I try to get a value of a removed element. But it didn't work.

Comment: And how can I acces the values from the component class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Phone variable is undefined because when you set phone to false, `#phone` element is not rendered.

Hide rows instead of remove:

```
<tr [hidden]="!phone">
```

and

```
<tr [hidden]="phone">
```

---

### `*ngIf` vs `[hidden]`

From angularjs official documentation:

> Hiding an element is quite different from removing an element with
>   NgIf.
>
> When you hide an element, that element and all of its descendents
>   remain in the DOM. All components for those elements stay in memory
>   and Angular may continue to check for changes. You could be holding
>   onto considerable computing resources and degrading performance, for
>   something the user can't see.
>
> When NgIf is false, Angular removes the element and its descendents
>   from the DOM. It destroys their components, potentially freeing up
>   substantial resources, resulting in a more responsive user experience.
>
> The show/hide technique is fine for a few elements with few children.
>   You should be wary when hiding large component trees; NgIf may be the
>   safer choice.
>
> *https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ngif*

Comment: okay, this works. Now I can save the data. Problem is that I now have to clear all the input fileds, when changing the radio position. Thats not exactly what I hoped for. But if it's the only way, I'll use it.

Comment: Yes, you have to clear fields manually. Read about https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms. I prefer this way over template forms.

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies in `usePhone` function. You are setting `this.phone` to boolean and are using it in html
as refrence to your `input` tag. You just need to change refrence variable name of the `input` tag like:

```
<td><input #phoneRef /></td>
```

And on click pass `phoneRef.value`:

```
<button (click)="add(name.value, phoneRef.value, email.value);">
```

Answer (score 0):

We cant access variable inside *ngIf , you can use [hidden]

```
<tr [hidden]="!phone">
    <td><label>phone</label></td>
    <td><input #phone2 /></td>
</tr>
<tr [hidden]="phone">
    <td><label>email</label></td>
    <td><input #email /></td>
</tr>
```